# How to reproduce Asymptotic Bounds of Recurrences in Wolframalpha

Tags: difference-equations, asymptotics, discrete, functional

In [Wolframalpha's Examples for Recurrences](https://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/mathematics/discrete-mathematics/recurrences/), there are bunch of Asymptotic Bounds of Recurrences examples, like [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%5Bn%5D+%3D+n%5E2+%2B+n%5E5+%2B+Log%5Bn%5D+%2B+18+a%5Bn%2F5%5D+%2B+13+a%5Bn%2F3%5D&lk=3)

It can get perfect result:
`a(n)~(759375 n^5)/714376 as n->∞`

How can I get this in Mathematica?

```
RSolve[a[n] == n^2 + n^5 + Log[n] + 18 a[n/5] + 13 a[n/3], a[n], n] // Simplify


AsymptoticRSolveValue[{a[n] == n^2 + n^5 + Log[n] + 18 a[n/5] + 13 a[n/3], a[1] == 1}, a[n], n -> \[Infinity]]
```

I try to use above two commands, but cannot get same result as Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Look for `AsymptoticRSolveValue`!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I've updated my post. Still cannot reproduce wolframaplha's example

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica 12.2 can't solve it either. Perhaps v13 is able to solve it?

Workaround:
Wolframalpha gives a hint concerning the derivative of the reccurence equation.

The derivative of the difference equation gives

```
rde = D[-a[n] + n^2 + n^5 + Log[n] + 18 a[n/5] + 13 a[n/3], n] /.a'[x_] -> as[x]
(*1/n + 2 n + 5 n^4 + 18/5 as[n/5] + 13/3 as[n/3] - as[n]*)
```

Assuming a solution `as[n]~n^\[Alpha]` we get

```
Asymptotic[rde /. as -> (#^\[Alpha] &), n -> Infinity]
(* ConditionalExpression[5 n^4, 1 < \[Alpha] < 4]*)
```

for `as[n]=a'[n]`.

That means the asymptotic solution must be `a[n] ~c n^5`!

Substituting in the original equation gives

```
-a[n] + n^2 + n^5 + Log[n] + 18 a[n/5] + 13 a[n/3] /. a -> (c #^5 &) //Asymptotic[#, n -> Infinity] &
(*n^5 - (714376 c n^5)/759375*)

Solve[%==0,c][[1]]
(*{c -> 759375/714376}*)
```

which confirms the solution given by Wolframalpha.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help. I thought Wolfram alpha was just an online simplified version of mathematica. Mathematica can at least cover all functionalities of Alpha. It seems not.